# Generate heat-map of cyclical continuous features - 24-hour time

Tags: python, pandas, time, heatmap, scatter-plot

Having a Pandas DF with hour of day, I've calculated the sin/cos time feature, [based on this article](https://ianlondon.github.io/blog/encoding-cyclical-features-24hour-time/):

```
  counter        hour      sin_time      cos_time
0       1           1  2.588190e-01  9.659258e-01
1       0           2  5.000000e-01  8.660254e-01
2       2           3  7.071068e-01  7.071068e-01
3       0           4  8.660254e-01  5.000000e-01
...
19      0          20 -8.660254e-01  5.000000e-01
20      0          21 -7.071068e-01  7.071068e-01
21      1          22 -5.000000e-01  8.660254e-01
22      0          23 -2.588190e-01  9.659258e-01
```

I'm trying to plot a heat-map based on the X,Y of the sin/cos time and the value of the counter, so if the counter is 0 no point is added. I've googeled around and written the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some test data
x = raw_df_tz['sin_time']
y = raw_df_tz['cos_time']

heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=50)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]

plt.clf()
plt.imshow(heatmap.T, extent=extent, origin='lower')
plt.show()
```

Output:

---

[image]

How can I incorporate the counter value and influence the char accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Found out that you can add weights argument to histogram2d:

```
np.histogram2d(x, y, weights=w, bins=50)
```

so w is my counter column:
[image]